# How to add a subview to a listview item onClick android

Tags: android, listview, onclick, android-fragments, listitem

I am using ListFragments and android version ICS

I have a list view with items

eg. 
list item 1

```
list item 2
list item 3
```

when user clicks on any list item i wan to show a sub view

eg : list item 1

```
 list item 2 
   subview
 list item 3
```

any help would be of great use.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are looking for is [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).